# how to publish 15000 TIFF files on GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, mosaic, geotiff-tiff

have ortophotos of an area that I need to serve as a baselayer of my map in openlayers, i'am using geoserver and php5.

i have 15000 files (1000MB each) in raw TIFF format with corresponding TFW word file - 15Tb of data. Coordinate system is EPSG:4326 (wgs84).

on geoserver there is "imagemosaic" option wich take the whole folder of tiffs to publish them - but it does not work for me. and i can create mosaic using QGIS, just the probleme it will take me forever to make one mosaic of these files

Comment: please say why something "does not work for" you

Comment: step one convert them to geotiffs with internal tiling and compression

Comment: As @iant sais you need first to convert them to tiled geotiffs. For this job you may use gdal. I think gdal_translate sould do the job for you. Check it  (http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html). And then you need to give some info on what goes wrong. like the geoserver log when failing.

Comment: I agree with @iant, I would start by converting the uncompressed tiffs into tiled tiffs with JPEG compression and YCBCR photometry. You will save more than 90% of disk space. Read http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/geotiff-compression-for-dummies.html and search "Geoserver on steroids" from the net. Remember that for the small scale view (zoom far out) the mosaic layer is not optimal. If server must open hundreds of images for covering the requested area it will be all too slow. You will need another layer(s) with coarse resolution as well to handle this situation.

Comment: sorry there are geotiffs with internal tiling and compression, the probleme with geoserver i have now he take to long to view them

Comment: You still haven't described the problem. We can't see the screen - you have to tell us exactly what you see, without "assumed knowledge" of what you have done, what the error or issue is, or what you expected to happen instead. Please be explicit.

Comment: You will need overviews (use gdaladdo for that) so GeoServer does not need to create an output image that has, let's say 40 m pixel size by resampling the full resolution imagery which has, let's say 1 m pixel size. I am sorry but I must recommend you to collect some background info before going to set up orthophoto service of the scale you are dealing with. The service that you build is not a big one, orthophoto services tend to be about that large, but it is certainly so big that it must be set up right. Did you already read http://www.slideshare.net/geosolutions/gs-steroids-foss4ge2014?

Comment: You also need to limit severely the zoom level at which the mosaic shows up, you cannot really expect geoserver to open all 15000 files and quickly generate an output image. If you need to see the data at all zoom levels, you'll have to create an image pyramid instead